# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) for Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I've been writing some code in haskell, and I just ran into the error above. I've looked on here for the answer, but couldn't find an answer that fixed my problem.

```
makeCtordecls :: RandomGen g => String -> RandomState g [Ctordecl]
makeCtordecls tp = do
  rng <- (randomRS (5 :: Int, 7 :: Int)
  let listOfCtordecl = replicateCountM rng (makeCtordecl (tp))
  return listOfCtordecl

replicateCountM :: (Applicative m) => Int -> (Int -> m a) -> m [a]
replicateCountM cnt0 f =
    loop cnt0
  where
    loop cnt
        | cnt <= 0  = pure []
        | otherwise = liftA2 (:) (f cnt) (loop (cnt - 1))
```

it is saying it is failing to parse at "let listOfCtordecl...."

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the paren on this line:

```
rng <- (randomRS (5 :: Int, 7 :: Int)
```

It should be:

```
rng <- (randomRS (5 :: Int, 7 :: Int))
```